# HTML/PHP form is not inserting data to phpadmin database

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am a complete beginner when it comes to PHP and mySQL. I am currently working on a simple project where a user would go to a form created in HTML and fill out some information and when they hit submit the data should theoretically be saved into a database. I created the form and each time it would be filled, it would then say that the account is created and no errors are being displayed. However, the information is not being inserted into the database on PHPadmin. I have been trying to solve this by looking at youtube videos and other stackoverflow forums but It is still not inserting. If someone could pinpoint what is wrong with my code that would be great.I will attach what I think is relevant in terms of code below.

```
Here is the main php file

<?php
$email = "";
$password = "";
$errors = array();

// connect to the database
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'bikeshop');

// check the connection 
if (!$db) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo "Connected successfully";

//if the register button is clicked
if (isset($_POST['register'])) {

    $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['firstname']);
    $lastname= mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['lastname']);
    $streetaddress = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['streetaddress']);
    $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['city']);
    $state = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['state']);
    $zipcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['zipcode']);
    $phonenumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['phonenumber']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

    // ensure that form fields are filled properly 
if (empty($email)) {
    array_push($errors, "Email is required"); 
}

if (empty($password)) {
    array_push($errors, "Password is required"); 
}

    // if there are no erros, save user to database

    if (count($errors) ==0) {
        $password = md5($password); //password encryption

        $sql = "INSERT INTO customer (FirstName, LastName, Address, City, State, Zip code, PhoneNumber, Email, Password) VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname','$streetaddress','$city','$state','$zipcode','$phonenumber','$email','$password')";

        if(!mysqli_query($db, $sql)) 
        {
            echo 'Account Created';
        }
        else 
        {
            echo 'Account creation failed';
        }

}

}

?>
```

```
Here is the errors.php file 

<?php if(count($errors) > 0): ?>
<div class="error">
    <?php foreach ($errors as $error): ?>
    <p><?php echo $error; ?></p>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

```
Here is the form section that I created in HTML

 <!-- Login page container -->
              <form method="post" action="register.php">
    <!-- display validation errors here --> 
    <?php include('errors.php'); ?> 

  <div class="container">
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
    <hr>

    <label for="firstname"><b>First Name</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter first name" name="firstname" required>

    <label for="lastname"><b>Last Name</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter last name" name="lastname" required>

    <label for="streetaddress"><b>Street Address</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Street Address" name="streetaddress" required>

    <label for="city"><b>City</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="City" name="city" required>

    <label for="state"><b>State</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter State" name="state" required>

    <label for="zipcode"><b>Zip Code</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Zip Code" name="zipcode" required>

    <label for="phonenumber"><b>Phone Number</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Phone Number" name="phonenumber" required>


    <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">

    <label for="password"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" value="<?php echo $password; ?>">

    <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>
    <button type="submit" name= "register" class="registerbtn">Register</button>
  </div>

  <div class="container signin">
    <p>Already have an account? <a href="internallogin.php">Sign in</a>.</p>
  </div>
           </form>
```

Comment: It looks like you're following a really, really old tutorial but please be aware that `md5` doesn't encrypt anything (it is a hashing algorithm) and should not be used in anymore.

Comment: phpmyadmin is not a database.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will invariably create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: [PHP the Right Way](https://phptherightway.com) is a good guide to learning PHP and links to many great resources. YouTube and forums are the absolute worst places to learn PHP because it's often a case of the uninformed trying their best to explain what wildly incorrect knowledge they have. This code you have here is extremely hazardous and isn't even useful from a learning perspective, it's full of red flags and massive security problems. This is how apps were developed in the late 1990s and PHP has changed considerably since then.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(count($errors) == 0)
```

should be changed with `if(empty($errors))`
that's because you're checking if an **array** is **equal to zero**. An array can be empty, while a varible can be null, zero, undefined (they're not the same though).

Comment: While this is a useful observation, this code is crippled with severe problems and patching them all is going to take a lot more than this.

Comment: @tadman of course, but since this looks like a school project (i really hope this code is not used in a real business) i just tried to help him achieve his goal and make a decent project which at least works

Comment: True, but advice like this that helps promote the use of really awful code is sometimes counter-productive. I appreciate where you're coming from, of course, I'm just saying sometimes not helping and explaining is better than doubling down on a chunk of hazardous code. Even if this is academic, there's far better examples to work from.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (isset($_POST['register'])) {

    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname= $_POST['lastname'];
    $streetaddress =  $_POST['streetaddress'];
    $city =  $_POST['city'];
    $state =  $_POST['state'];
    $zipcode =  $_POST['zipcode'];
    $phonenumber =  $_POST['phonenumber'];
    $email =  $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
```